# Why I get response 3 in my test account using authorize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm using Authorize.net payment gateway (SIM method) to my website & i've created test account and testing right now. At the end of the checkout, when I set redirection URL , i get error like this,

```
[x_response_code] => 3
[x_response_reason_code] => 92
[x_response_reason_text] => The gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration.
```

I am using sandbox test account to do this testing... Do I need to get original merchant account to test?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you are passing an invalid parameter that is no longer accepted by the SIM API.